esProc and Japersoft Studio fail to integrate
In esProc I created a simple query.
query
Then I created new Data Adapter in Jaspersoft Studio and added 2 jar files to Driver Classpath. The connection is successful.
Creation of Data Adapter (Database Location)
Creation of Data Adapter (Driver Classpath)
Also I created two xml files: config and dfxConfig and added these files to config directory of esProc.
config.xml
dfxConfig.xml
Later I added 2 jars, config directory and esProc scripts directory to classpath in Java Build Path.
Classpath
After all these steps when I try to call my departments.dfx file in Jaspersoft Studio I receive "Error in cell".
"Error in cell"
I tried using exec instead of call, tried using just departments (name of dfx file). In the last two cases the program doesn't react to the code at all. I have no idea where a mistake is.
Could anyone, please, help me?
